# How to create an alert for azure storage account if there is data action permissions assigned to a custom role or a built in role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, kql, azure-monitoring

How to create an alert using Kusto query when an Azure RBAC role (custom and built-in role) is assigned with a data action permission for azure storage account.

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write"
| extend Properties = parse_json(Properties)
| where Properties.targetResource.id contains "storageAccounts"
| where Properties_d.responseBody contains "dataActions" or Properties.responseBody contains "notDataActions"
| project TimeGenerated, PrincipalType=Properties.requestBody.properties.principalType, PrincipalName=Properties.requestBody.properties.principalName, RoleDefinitionName=Properties.requestBody.properties.roleDefinitionName, Scope=Properties.scope, Resource=Properties.targetResource
```

Comment: Do you mean how to actually create the alert (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/tutorial-log-alert) or is the query not working?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no logging on data action in Azure activity, you can get to know the logs about role assignment but not the data actions in it.

If you want to create a alert with Role assignment you can use below KQL query:

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue contains "MICROSOFT.AUTHORIZATION/ROLEASSIGNMENTS"
| extend Properties = parse_json(Properties)
```

[image]